# New US passport hasn't arrived in over 10 weeks. What to do next?

Tags: usa, passports, us-citizens, application-status

I applied on February 11th at an acceptance facility. In approximately April, a received a letter from the Department of State asking for more info, which I promptly provided within 2 weeks, and info which was confirmed delivered by me (via tracking number) to the Department of State on April 13th -- almost 3 weeks ago. My status on the site says, "`It is being processed.`" It has said this since the beginning and will not change. I contacted the Department, and this woman with a horrible attitude just basically summed everything down to, "`It's at their discretion, and there's nothing more I can tell you regarding your status.`" This was over a week ago.

I emailed them and they tell me to call them -- I call them and they tell me they can't do anything or tell me anything other than what the site says, so it's a waste of time for both parties here. The person in the email also stated that the, "`Site is having problems.`" I'm not too confident in that, but anyways...

What can I or should I do at this point? It's been well too long and they've left me without any closure.

I've looked around and heard that I could contact local congress to help me, but what could they do that I couldn't by inquiring information? I question whether such a thing would be helpful and how.

Maybe someone else has been in this dreaded position and can give some tips or options to me.

Note: this is not a renewal, but a first time passport.

Comment: It is true that your congressional representative can't do much more than you can in terms of getting information, but representatives have somewhat more clout and are more likely to get a faster response.  It has certainly worked that way for me in the past, though not with a passport application.  Representatives have staff members who deal with these sorts of requests as a matter of course, and they are also far more likely to have direct contact with people who are actually helpful; in your case you'll randomly be served by someone who may be less helpful, as you noticed.

Comment: @phoog Got it! Although I'd probably consider this only as a last resort option.

Comment: You're more likely to get a better response if you include in your question (1) whether you've had a passport before and, if not, (2) what proof of citizenship you supplied with your application.  If I were you I'd call my representative right now.  It's not a huge investment of time on your part, and delaying serves no purpose that I can see.  What are you waiting for?

Comment: @phoog I've already tried that, and it may no difference. I thought a better option would be to call everyday and annoy them, or (better option) try to expedite it by setting up travel plans to boost possible work time on their end. As to contacting the representatives, I can bet they'll probably want a consent of release form signed or something -- not a deal, but I don't think it's right that one should have to go through these methods for something like a passport. It's not like I'm on trial for murder.

Comment: I meant to say that you're more likely to get a better response from *travel.se* if you include that information in this question.  It seems likely to me that they are calling your proof of citizenship into question.  This is apparently common for certain types of cases.  A good response to your travel.se question would take that into account, if it is in fact relevant.  If you've had a passport before, however, it's very unlikely to be relevant.

Comment: They actually told me weeks ago that the "issue" as to why they wanted more info was that I had just gotten my ID renewed prior to application. Nevertheless, nothing has changed and there's no update on my passport status, and that piece of info serves as no indicator of my status as of the last (almost) 3 weeks.

Comment: But the information about why your application is being delayed is certainly relevant in answering the question "What ... should I do at this point."

Comment: @phoog I don't follow. Do you mean my last comment or the situation of contacting the State?

Comment: The State Department is currently quoting a [six week](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/information/processing-times.html) turnaround time for passports. It's only been three weeks since they got the additional information. I'm not sure what you want to happen here exactly. They have to take some amount of time to process it, and they don't really have any status to give you besides "please wait." If eventually the wait becomes too long or you need your passport sooner, you can contact your congressional representative for help. They help with this stuff all the time.

Comment: I assumed that your comment "that piece of info serves as no indicator of my status as of the last (almost) 3 weeks" meant that you don't think the reason for the delay is relevant.  I was explaining why I think it is relevant.

Comment: @ZachLipton It's been around 3 weeks since I provided them the additional info. I have been waiting in total for over 10 weeks since I applied in February. Those six weeks are counted from the time they receive the application, which I'm almost positive was at least 8 weeks ago.

Comment: If the wait becomes too long, they should eventually tell me why. Either tell me it's denied or it's on its way -- them saying nothing for extended periods of time seems like the whole application got lost in the mix somehow and they won't clarify anything regarding it.

Comment: @phoog It was relevant as to why they inquired more info from me, but I don't see how that can serve as any basis as to why it's now been nearly 3 weeks after they have received the info and absolutely no change in status/word/info regarding my application.

Comment: Here's how it could be related: applications with your particular circumstances may be processed by a specific office with a heavier backlog. My point is not about the relationship between your circumstances and the processing time, but rather about that between your circumstances and the steps you should take to follow up. It seems to me that you could have called your representative in the time it's taken you to type these comments; I don't think they'd need a release form or anything, but if they do, what does it matter? It will add less time to the process than this conversation has.

Comment: @SeyCharl, this is expected to be [a busy year for renewals](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/01/31/travel/passport-renewal.html?_r=0) so they may be slow. Note that the [link provided above about processing times](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/information/processing-times.html) says "As of Tuesday, May 3, 2016, we are processing routine applications in approximately 6 weeks from the time of application". If they asked for additional documentation your application was not "routine", so it will take longer. I'd wait a few more weeks, if you can, before getting too upset.

Comment: @Dennis I am not renewing, but thanks -- I see your point. I will continue to wait at least a week or so longer before taking on extra steps.

Comment: Okay, the Department has finally stated that it's been mailed to me now. I guess I was a little impatient. Thanks for your time everybody!

Answer (score 4):

Processing time for routine applications are "approximately six weeks" according to the [website of the U.S. Department of State](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/information/processing-times.html):

> As of Monday, June 20, 2016, we are processing routine applications in approximately 6 weeks from the time of application.

This is up [from 4 weeks in 2015](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/01/31/travel/passport-renewal.html?_r=0).

In your case the time from 11 February to sometime in the beginning of April corresponds roughly to those six weeks of processing time, i.e. it took them that long to look to it. Since you needed to send additional info (arriving on their desks on April 14), it seems your case took to another round of waiting for processing, which, as you state in your final comment, lasted roughly another 3 weeks until 7 May.
I'm afraid that this is how public institutions work and especially since there was no time-pressure about upcoming travels to your case.

In case you do need the passport urgently, [expedited procedures are described on the same website.](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/information/processing-times.html)